# Old School RuneScape kingdom management: what's the difference between collecting resources daily and weekly?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In Old School RuneScape, I currently have 10 of my 15 [Miscellanian subjects](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Managing_Miscellania) collecting herbs and the other 5 collecting maple logs.

I collect my kingdom's produced resources weekly (every seven days), topping up my favor and coffers when I do.

**With the same allocation of workers (10 herb, 5 maple), how much more would my kingdom produce if I maintained it daily rather than weekly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Collecting daily will slightly improve (+2-3%) our yields of herbs and logs, but give *fewer* herb seeds and bird's nests because of unfavorable daily rounding.**

We can arrive at this answer quite easily using RuneHQ's excellent **[Miscellania Management calculator](http://www.runehq.com/calculator/miscellania-management)**.

To calculate a full week's gathering, we set the calculator with at least 1.2M gold in the coffer, duration of 7 days, and the specified distribution of workers (10 herb gatherers, 5 maple choppers). This returns 410 herbs, 3 herb seeds, 3025 maple logs, and 30 bird's nests.

Repeating the process to get a day's output, we set the calculator with at least 750K gold in the coffer, duration of 1 day, and the same distribution of workers. This gives us a daily output of 60 herbs, 0 herb seeds, 445 maple logs, and 4 bird's nests. Multiplying this by 7 (days in a week) yields 420 herbs, 0 herb seeds, 3115 maple logs, and 28 bird's nests.

Although the herb and maple log yields improve slightly if we collect resources from the kingdom daily, the yields of maple logs and herb seeds, somewhat counterintuitively, decline! This is likely because of unfavorable rounding forced by collecting the resources daily, rather than weekly.

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly enough to bother maintaining a daily reap of your crop.

http://services.runescape.com/m=forum/forums.ws?98,99,877,62965146

Posts 9 & 10 on page 1 give a tabled outcome of daily vs weekly workers to answer your question, but reading the whole thing will help understand why.

Comment: As the link can go dowm, can you copy the table here. Pictures allowed too

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE!  While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.